# redis connection error when trying to connect to SSL port 6380 of azure redis to Azure app service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, docker-container, azure-appservice, azure-redis-cache

I m trying to connect azure app service(Ruby Application) to azure redis cache using port 6380, the configuration works fine with 6379 port , but when I try to switch port to 6380 , Application goes down. At Azure redis cache I have changed port to SSL 6380 and in app configuration I have changed the port, made changes in docker-compose.yml and health spec files.

logs of azure app service.
2023-12-05T07:07:10.843490689Z Failed to forward request to http://169.254.132.4:3000. Encountered a System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception after 300001.731ms with message: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 300 seconds elapsing.. Check application logs to verify the application is properly handling HTTP traffic.

Below are the Application logs.
[6ebfc8ce-252d-461f-8f5d-58ddaa029395] Redis::TimeoutError (Connection timed out):
[6ebfc8ce-252d-461f-8f5d-58ddaa029395]
[6ebfc8ce-252d-461f-8f5d-58ddaa029395] redis (4.0.3) lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:71:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'

Also We are using docker container for redis , also changed the container port to 6380

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
05c4c9cc6bc9   redis:latest      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago      Up 2 days      0.0.0.0:6380->6379/tcp, :::6380->6379/tcp

I have set the changed the port to 6380 in docker-compose.yml file
 `redis:                                                                                                                    container_name: bancs_redis                                                                                             image: redis:latest                                                                                                     command: redis-server                                                                                                   ports:                                                                                                                    - '6380:6380'                                                                                                         volumes:                                                                                                                  - redis:/data:consistent`

I have changed the port in .env file.

`export REDIS_URL='bancscache.redis.cache.windows.net' export REDIS_PORT=6380 export REDIS_DB=2` 
At azure app service I have set the configuration to port: 6380 and At Azure redis cache changed port to SSL only which is using 6380 port.

Comment: could share the Dockerfile  with the Docker.yml file and share the code